# waiting fetch to get the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On a vue application, on a component, calling API to get some data... the problem is that getting **undefined**, before the **call ends**... Possible needed aync/await but getting error when adding

```
//component code (login.vue)

import store from "@/store";

const { response, error } = store.postTO(url, [{id: "button1"}, {id: "button2"}, {id: "button3"}]);
if (response) {
  console.log(response);
} else {
  console.warn(error);
}


//store.js
export default {
    user : null,
    postTO
}


function postTO(url, postData) {

    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    };
    
    return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(response => 
         response.json().then(data => ({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        })
    ).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        return {response : res.data, error : "test"};
    }))
    .catch(error => {
        return {response : "test", error : error};
    });

}
```

illustrated
[image]

Comment: because is is an async process, you need to wait for the results. if you are using vuex. then call the `postTO ` from any method and after API result mutate it to a vuex state variable, read the variable to vue back

Comment: You also need to await store.postTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component you have to wait for the fetch by putting an await before the store.posTo